# Difference of Divergent Products Converges?

Tags: limits, infinite-product

I was thinking about series and was wondering how infinite *products* are dealt with. For example, consider this difference of two divergent products:

$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \ln(n) - \prod_{n=2}^\infty (\ln(n)-1/n)$$

I don't know how to determine bounds for the difference, or prove if it converges to a limit. I remember one can take the logarithm of an infinite product to convert it into an infinite sum, but I don't think that strategy applies here because it is a difference of infinite products, not a single infinite product. I really don't know how to deal with the difference of products like this. If someone is familiar with this type of situation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant to write $~\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}~\prod_{n=2}^N\ln(n)~-~\prod_{n=2}^N\bigg[\ln(n)-\dfrac1n\bigg],~$ otherwise the expression

would make little sense, since $\infty-\infty$ is undetermined. Now, factor $\ln(n)$ inside the latter, and

split it into two products, then factor $~\displaystyle\prod_{n=2}^N\ln(n)~$ in both sides, and you'll get $P_1(1-P_2)$, whose

asymptotics you'll then have to evaluate, which you'll do by assessing the order of both $P_1$ and

$P_2$ individually. This will be done by taking their [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series), and employing an estimation

based on [integral approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_formula). Be warned, this will probably involve special functions, such

as the [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) or [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), for instance. The limit ultimately diverges.